# Proof bijectivity of map between a hyperbolic plane $\mathcal{H}^2$ and open unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: functions, hyperbolic-geometry

Given a hyperbolic plane $\mathcal{H}^2=\{(t,x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^3|t^2=x^2+y^2+1, t>0\}$, I had to construct a function $f$ that maps as follows: For a point $P$ in $\mathcal{H}^2$, draw a line $l$ from this point to $(-1, 0, 0)$. The function $f$ maps every point $P$ to the intersection of $l$ with the $xy-$plane. I figured that the $l$ was given by $$ l: \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + \lambda \begin{pmatrix} t+1 \\ x \\ y \end{pmatrix}.$$

Then $f$ will be defined as
\begin{align*}
f:\;\mathcal{H}^2&\to\mathcal{D}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x^2 + y^2 < 1\} \\
    (t,x,y) &\mapsto \big(\frac{1}{t+1}x, \frac{1}{t+1}y\Big).
\end{align*}

**Assuming** this function does as I require I tried to proof bijectivity by proving injectivity and surjectivity, **but failed on both fronts**.

For injectivity I tried:
Injective when $f(t_1, x_1, y_1)=f(t_2, x_2, y_2)\implies(t_1,x_1,y_1)=(t_2,x_2,y_2)$. So we want to show: $\big(\frac{1}{t_1+1}x_1, \frac{1}{t_1+1}y_1\Big)=\big(\frac{1}{t_2+1}x_2, \frac{1}{t_2+1}y_2\Big)\implies (t_1,x_1,y_1)=(t_2,x_2,y_2)$. From here I don't know how to continue because $x$ is a based on both $x_1$ and $y_1$ (based on $x_1$ because it's based on $t_1$). I tried filling in $t_1$ and $t_2$ as terms of $x_1,y_1$ and $x_2,y_2$ respectively, but this yielded me equations that I don't know how to work with:
$$
x_1(t_2 + 1)=x_2(t_1+1)\\
y_1(t_2 + 1)=y_2(t_1+1).
$$

For surjectivity I tried:
Let $(x_1,y_1)\in\mathcal{D}$, then we want to show that there is a $q\in\mathcal{H}^2$ such that $f(q)=(x_1,y_1)$. I tried finding such a $q$, but didn't know how to incorporate the restrictions on $t$.

EDIT: I then thought that for all $(x_1,y_1)$, we could have $f(t, x_1(t+1), y_1(t+1))=(x_1,y_1)$. Which is true, but how do I confirm that $(t, x_1(t+1), y_1(t+1))$ is in $\mathcal{H}^2$.

*Some things I noted:*

Because for every element $(t,x,y)\in\mathbb{H}^2$ we have that $t^2=x^2+y^2+1$, we have that $t=\pm\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}$, but because we also require $t>0$, we have $t=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}$, so $t$ is a function of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way to transform between the hyperboloid model and the Poincaré disk model. Maybe you could try to do the 1-dimensional case first (just assume that y is always 0, so you map between a hyperbola and a segment, which is easy to visualize on a picture), and then generalize to more dimensions? In more dimensions, it works the same as in 1 dimension, because all the equations do not change when you rotate in the (x,y) plane.

Comment: Yeah, but t depends on x and y, but every time i try something to prove surjecticity, my x and y also depend on t

Comment: @ZenoRogue For surjectivity I thought for example that $f(t, a(t+1), b(t+1)) = (a,b)$ for all $(a,b)\in \mathcal{D}$, but how do I prove that $(t, a(t+1), b(t+1))\in\mathcal{H}$?

Comment: You should prove that (as long as $(a,b) \in \mathcal{D}$) there is exactly one $t$ which satifies the equation $t^2 = a^2(t+1)^2 + b^2(t+1)^2 + 1$. This is a quadratic equation, so it is easy to solve. Especially that one of the roots is -1.

Comment: @ZenoRogue I managed to prove it by creating an inverse function. Should I write an answer myself?